# How do I execute a command with a new .exe in powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, openssl

I want to decrypt a file that is AES encryptet, with a script on powershell. To decrypt it I want to use a openSSL binary, that the script automatically downloads.
When I execute the openssl.exe with `start-Process -FilePath "$pwd\openssl\openssl.exe"` a new cmd-window opens and I can enter my command to decrypt the file there. (which works I have tested it)
So my question:
Is there a way to execute the command `openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -in secrets.txt.enc -out secrets.txt.new` with the .exe without having to manually input it into the new window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Start-Process`, you can pass the parameters with `-ArgumentList`:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$pwd\openssl\openssl.exe" -ArgumentList "aes-256-cbc -d -a -in secrets.txt.enc -out secrets.txt.new"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try this:

```
& ".\openssl\openssl.exe" aes-256-cbc -d -a -in secrets.txt.enc -out secrets.txt.new
```